# Get element from array constant?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If you have a CSE array constant as follows in cell A1:

```
{={2,4,6,8}}
```

How can you get a specific element from the array constant? I tried the following formulas but they all return the first value of the array constant (2).

```
=INDEX(A1, 0)
=INDEX(A1, 1)
```

However, it does work if the array is not a reference. The following formula returns the 3rd element (6).

```
=INDEX({2,4,6,8},3)
```

Thank you

Comment: That is because you are not actually referencing the array but the value in cell `A1`. And surprisingly that is not an array but just the value 2 since Excel version prior to ms365 use implicit intersection to just return a single value. Effectively your formula means `INDEX(2, 1)`. And if the 2nd parameter changes it will still return 2 since it will revert back to the last element on your single-element array. Only if you have ms365 you could reference a spilling dynamic array.

Comment: Omg I have tried this so many times and haven't found a resolution yet. I want to store entire arrays into cells to simplify my math and extracting the elements has been a **major** stumbling block for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the array constant in a Name instead of a cell.

[image: array constant as named range]

Then INDEX will work with it properly with no implicit intersection.

Or you could parse the formula using the FORMULATEXT function, but that sounds tedious.

Answer (score 0):

Try `=INDEX(A1#,1)`. The `#` tells excel that `A1` is a spill formula (more than 1 cell long). The array index starts at 1, not 0 in this case.

As a side note, `Index` knows you are referring to an index, not a row, when you give it a 1D array. In your example `=INDEX(A1#,4)` and `=INDEX(A1#,1,4)` return the Fourth item in your array (8 in this case), but `=INDEX(A1#,4,1)` will give you the error `#REF!`. If you define your array vertically `{={2;4;6;8}}`, `=INDEX(A1#,4)` and  `=INDEX(A1#,4,1)` both work.

Edit: It looks like this does not always work in Excel 365 when a an array formula is created using `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`. I *think* this is due to the changes in 365. Array formulas have pretty much been replaced with spill formulas. Entering `={2,4,6,8}` is mostly equivalent to a pre-365 array formula, but creating an array formula with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter` confines the output to as many cells as selected. In Dan's case, he selected only one cell and the formula doesn't automatically spill, so the formula is confined only to that cell. Excel seems to treat that cell as if it only contains that array element. If you select 2 cells and enter an array formula then `=INDEX(A1#,2)` will work but `=INDEX(A1#,3)` returns `#REF!`.

Edit2: It is possible with the `FORMULATEXT` Function as @DickKusleika suggested. Here is a function adapted from [ExcelJet](https://exceljet.net/formula/split-text-with-delimiter) that does the job.

```
=LET(
    DesiredIndex, 1,
    ArrayFormulaRef, A1,

    Formula, FORMULATEXT(ArrayFormulaRef),
    FormulaLen, LEN(Formula),
    CSVStart, FIND("{",Formula,2),

    CSV, MID(LEFT(Formula,FormulaLen-1),CSVStart+1,FormulaLen),

    TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(CSV,",",REPT(" ",LEN(CSV))),(DesiredIndex-1)*LEN(CSV)+1,LEN(CSV)))
)
```

Comment: In this case I don't have a spill formula since the array constant is entered with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER (CSE). Tried it anyway and did not work. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Dan, What version of excel are you using? Using `#` with the array formula works for me with for Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.14326.20164) 64-bit.

Comment: What you suggest does work for me if I have an array that spills into neighbor cells. But I wanted to avoid the spilling... so I entered the array with CSE. And then it doesn't work. 

I do have Excel 365: MSO (16.0.14131.20358) 64-bit.

Comment: @Dan, Hmmm... When I changed my spill formula to an array formula, it stayed spread out over 4 cells and index worked. I had to delete the array and re-enter it to replicate your error. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Any ideas on how to solve it in this specific scenario?

Comment: @Dan, See my edit. This may have worked pre-365 but it doesn't work now (that I know of). If you share more about what you're doing, maybe we can figure out an alternate solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237242/discussion-between-dave-thunes-and-dan-aronne).